# Is it possible to bridge TLSv1 traffic to TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3

Tags: ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I've got a web application with nginx supporting https with TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 protocols. We'd like to stop supporting TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 due to well known security vulnerabilities. Unfortunately, we have some legacy clients running very old OSes that cannot be upgraded to connect over TLSv1.2. As a solution would it be possible to place a proxy in front of our web app that takes traffic solely from these legacy clients and have that proxy support decrypting TLSv1 but re-encrypt that traffic using TLSv1.2 before proxying it forward? Is this something that nginx can do? Would the responses returned to the client be encrypted with TLSv1?

Comment: How do you authenticate your clients?  If you're authenticating clients by the client PKI certificate, you'd need to have the client's private keys to do the reencryption and carry though the actual identification via client cert to the back-end TLSv1.2 server.

Comment: We are not authenticating clients via certificate, this is done via HTTP basic auth.

Comment: Use 2 different names (or even IPs to be extra safe if you have clients not supporting SNI properly) pointing to the same nginx, and configure them differently regarding TLS. That way, no need for a proxy.

Comment: Interesting idea Patrick Mevzek. Is there any issue with TLSv1 insecurities causing compromise of a server itself or is it just compromise of traffic passing through the server?